# ajax popup load from another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

on button click load popup.. but its stay on main page.. i want to load it from ajax.php and button `data-id="1521"` send like this `ajax.php?id=1521` how to do it plz help me for this...

css style

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/style.min.css">
```

content codes

```
<ul id="products">
<li>
<div class="image"><img src="../someimage.jpg"><div>
<div class="name">Samsung 65' Curved LED 4K TV</div>
<div class="cart"><button type="button" class="button small" data-id="1521">Add to Cart</button><div>
</li>
</ul>
```

This is jquery popup.. `But this one i want to load from ajax.php`

```
<div id="popup">
  <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
    If you can't get it up use<br><span class="logo">bPopup</span>
</div>
<div id="popup2">
  <span class="button b-close"><span>X</span></span>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/jquery.bpopup-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/assets/scripting.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe you are looking for jQuery `.load()`. [Check docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: can u give me a code from js plzzz i want to send `data-id` also

Comment: So you want the content of the dialog to be loaded from ajax.php?

Comment: i want to `<div id="popup">` load from ajax.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample code you can alter at your convenience to match your requirements:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $('#products').find('.button').on('click', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/ajax.php',
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (html) {
                $('body').append(html);
                $(html).bPopup();
            },
            error: function (returnValue) {}
        });
    });


});
```

This is done with the use of jQuery's [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Providing that `ajax.php` contains only the HTML of the popup.

Comment: not work check this link plzz http://sriads.com/shopping/test4.php

Comment: What do you mean by *not work*? (your link works fine)

Comment: its not load from ajax.php

Comment: Please provide more info, such as any console errors, the request details if any, please be specific (have you amended `path/to/ajax.php`?).

Comment: yes.. if u can plzz check this link: http://sriads.com/shopping/test4.php

Comment: I *already* checked that link, everything works fine...

Comment: yeah.. but popup not load from ajax.php  its load from same page test4.php `<div id="popup">`

Comment: Please put the code I provided you with **after** you include jQuery. In any case, it would result in a `404` as `http://sriads.com/ajax.php` doesn't exists. Please use `url: 'ajax.php'` (there is no leading `/`).

Comment: plzz check now this url : http://sriads.com/shopping/ajax.php
i remove `<div id="popup">` code from test4.php and i put to ajax.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80850/discussion-between-d4v1d-and-user3501407).

Comment: @user3501407 - Please stop using comments to ask others to visit your questions. I just removed a pile of these from across the site. That's an improper use of comments.

Answer (score 3):

Add a div for ex `<div id="popup"></div>"` and place this is in a `<script>`

```
var id = $('button').data('id');
$("#popup").load('ajax.php?id='+id);
```

This will load the content in the new div call popup

To make this effect on button click add an id to your button and call the above script on

```
$('#buttonid').on('click',function(){
// the above script
});
```